# Performing Lookups in Nifi DistributedCache

Tags: apache-nifi

I am configuring a sample lookup in nifi where in I am putting a sample record using `PutDistributedMapCache` in `distributedcache`. Now I have configfured a `Lookup record processor` which reads a sample json and looks up for two attributes in the distributed cache and populates a field.

Cache Entry Identifier : ${id_store},${id_product}

Flow:
[image]

[image]

LookupRecord config

[image]

[image]

[image]

Generate flow file which goes to putcache :
[image]

Generate flow file for lookuprecord:

[image]
The problem is the lookup is always sending records in unmatched relationship and the value for `value_product1` is always coming null. 
Please help me with anything missing .

**UPDATE:**

Changed cache entry identifier .
[image]

Lookup record key changed to :

[image]

Error in LookupRecord:( I have double checked my schemas for JSON)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your first screenshot, the config for PutDistributedMapCache shows the Cache Entry Identifier as "id_store,id_product". The value should have expression language and should probably be `${id_store}_${id_product}`. Lets say store id was "1" and product id was"2", this would create an entry in the cache with key "1_2".

In LookupRecord, the DistributedMapCacheLookupService only takes a single key and you have key and key2. You need to make key be a record path statement that concatenates the id_store and id_product to form the same key as above. So `concat(/id_store, '_', /id_product)`

Comment: Thanks Bryan for the input , I have made the suggested changes but lookup is still not happening . Updated the question with screen shots

Comment: Waiting for your input Bryan :)

Comment: The GenerateFlowFile that goes to PutDistributedMapCache does not have any attributes named "id_store" or "id_product", it only has JSON in the content of the flow file. In order to reference values in Cache Entry Identifier, you need attributes, you can add user defined properties in GenerateFlowFile which will become attributes.

Comment: So i added two user defined properties in this GenerateFlowFile , attr1 - ${id_store}  and attr2 {id_product} . Is this correct ? After I did this , still lookup is failing. When I check for the attribute section in data provenance for putcache , its coming as empty.

Comment: No, the properties should be id_store = 1 and id_product = 3 or whatever matches the json you have

Comment: If for some reason you want to call them attr1 and attr2, then you need to change your Cache Entry Identifier to ${attr1}_${attr2}

Comment: No its fine I changed it , so my idea is lookup these values . So according to you I should put three attributes in my GenerateFlowFile for putcache , otherwise how will I lookup the value for value_product1?  I am getting a bit confused here.

Comment: You only need attributes to create the cache key dynamically in PutDistributedMapCache, since your key is id_store and id_product, you only need attributes for those, you could also hard-code the value of Cache Entry Identifier to 1_3 for testing and then you wouldn't need any attributes.

Comment: Also, right now you are creating a cache entry with key of store_produce and a value of your JSON document. So when LookupRecord goes to the LookupService and says give me the value for this key, its going to get back the JSON document and try to put that into value_product1 and I'm not sure if that what you want

Comment: You probably want the Custom Text of GenerateFlowFile that goes to PutDistributedMapCache to have only a single number like ${now():toNumber()} this way the value of the cache entry is a single number and not json.

Comment: Yes exactly thats what is needed , I understood now what you are saying. After doing the above changes I am getting an error of jsonformatexception in lookuprecord

Comment: see my use case is to lookup for multiple keys and populate single or multiple values . So i need to work accordingly.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure I follow your last statement, you can only get one value back per LookupRecord and the result goes into "Result Record Path", the value coming back could be a record itself, but in your case you are putting the result in /value_product1 and that field is an int so the result of the lookup has to be a single int

Comment: Yea so the Lookup worked correctly and since the value of your cache entry was JSON, it took the JSON and put it into the field value_product1 but that field is an int in your schema

Comment: Okay so in the practical scenario , I can have a record and I need to look up for two fields and extract one value out of it . My idea was to send a json and cache some fields and lookup on other field. How should I make this work now ? Please suggest . Should I change my generateflow file for putcache ? If yes how will I show the use case of a record

Comment: I described in a comment above how to setup GenerateFlowFile for PutDistributedMapCache, you want the content of the flow file (Custom Text) to be the value you want to end up in value_product1, so it needs to be a single number

Comment: Thanks Bryan I just saw it , but can you suggest me how can i configure my lookup in way that I can cache multiple records in distributedcache and do a multi key lookup on the value.

Comment: Need to see examples that demonstrate what you want to achieve, if you need to lookup more than one thing then you need to chain together multiple LookupRecord processors

Comment: Lets say in this scenario , my generate flow file is expected to generate only one columns , i.e. value_product1 and keys are configured as attributes. Is it not possible to cache the whole record and use attribute to extract value_product1 ? That is my confusion. I understood for multiple values we might need multiple lookup processors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198545/discussion-between-aviral-kumar-and-bryan-bende).

Comment: @AviralKumar did you ever get this working and possibly have screen shots of how you configured your flow to work? I'm newish to NiFi and have a similar issue where I think I need to store thousands of ids to a cache to lookup later.

Comment: you can cache the records in distributed map cache in nifi and perform a lookup using LookupRecord processor